# Updating value of particular keys in MultiKeyMap in Java

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, multikey

I was trying to update the values of set of particular keys in `MultiKeyMap` in Java but not able to get how to do that.

Suppose I want to update (key1, key2, value1) same set of key with different value (key1, key2, value2).

If I simply perform put in `MultiKeyMap` then it create new row and doesn't update the value. `replace()` is also not working.

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.collections4.map.LinkedMap;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.map.MultiKeyMap;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

        List<Double> list11 = new ArrayList<Double>();
        list11.add((double) 3);
        list11.add((double) 5000);
        
        List<Double> list22 = new ArrayList<Double>();
        list22.add((double) 7);
        list22.add((double) 2000);
        
        MultiKeyMap<String, List<Double>> multiKeyMap = new MultiKeyMap<String, List<Double>>();
        multiKeyMap.put("sourcecode11", "basecode11", "productcode11", list11);
        multiKeyMap.put("sourcecode22", "basecode22", "productcode22", list22);
        
        String source = "sourcecode11";
        String base = "basecode11";
        String product = "productcode11";
        
        if (multiKeyMap.containsKey(source, base, product)) {
            List<Double> fees = multiKeyMap.get(source, base, product);
            Double count = fees.get(0);
            Double amount = fees.get(1);
            
            count +=1;
            amount+=500;
            List<Double> list33 = new ArrayList<Double>();
            list33.add(count);
            list33.add(amount);
            multiKeyMap.
            multiKeyMap.replace(source, base, product, list33);
        }
        

    }

}
```

Getting error at replace function

> not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String, List<Double>)

Please provide solution for updating value in MultiKeyMap.

maven dependency :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use put in order to replace (key1,key2,key3) with new value list.
Your code run correct with this exemple

```
    List<Double> list11 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double> list22 = new ArrayList<>();
    list22.add((double) 7);
    list22.add((double) 2000);

    MultiKeyMap<String, List<Double>> multiKeyMap = new MultiKeyMap<>();
    multiKeyMap.put("sourcecode11", "basecode11", "productcode11", list11);
    multiKeyMap.put("sourcecode22", "basecode22", "productcode22", list22);

    String source = "sourcecode22";
    String base = "basecode22";
    String product = "productcode22";

    if (multiKeyMap.containsKey(source, base, product)) {
        List<Double> fees = multiKeyMap.get(source, base, product);
        System.out.println("before :" + multiKeyMap);
        Double count = fees.get(0);
        Double amount = fees.get(1);
        count += 1;
        amount += 500;
        List<Double> list33 = new ArrayList<>();
        list33.add(count);
        list33.add(amount);
        multiKeyMap.put(source, base, product, list33);
        System.out.println("after :" + multiKeyMap);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is confusing. You are working on the List 'fees' by getting 'count' and 'amount', incrementing them and then *appending* the incremented values as two *new* values to the List. Please tell us what's going on there.

It's also alarming that you seem to be treating a List as some sort of data-encapsulating class.

Comment: This is some simple illustration of updation the values of the keys set. There are several formulas that I have to apply instead of just incrementation. To reduce the the code I haven't added this. Please provide how to update count and amount in the keyset.

Comment: Sorry - I slightly misread it. You can just use put to add your new replacement List as Maroine said